# How to DIY Bed that can support 600+ pounds?

Tags: attic, bedroom, bed

I’m trying to go ahead and design a bed before I buy everything I need to build it, however when it comes to the weight capacity of the bed, I am unsure how to maximize it. It’s going to be a loft bed with a secret room underneath and I need the actual bed to be able to handle 600+ pounds. Me and my spouse are rather on the larger side (though we are working on that issue). I would like the entire project to have some kind of rubber “feet” possibly in case something gets spilled, I wouldn’t want the wood to get hurt. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: 20psf×80in×80in×1sqft/144sqin = 888#. 30psf => 1333#. For plywood span ratings, e.g. 32/16, the first number is the 20psf span rating and the second number is the 40psf span rating. Table R802.4.1(2) from the IRC provides 30psf framing sizes (10 dead plus 20 live).

Comment: Rather than building your own lateral stability bracing, attaching to a wall (or better yet 2 walls at a corner) is the way to go. A ledger along the wall with the same depth as the floor joists is a fine header if it's fastened to each wall stud.

Comment: Instead of putting posts at the frame corners, you might find your floor joist locations and cheat any posts around so that they land directly on floor joists. Floor sheathing should be strong enough for the post's punching shear, but there would be a noticeable difference in stiffness.

Comment: For 7 ft long joists running perpendicular to a header that we're now sizing, take a "building width" of 7ft to IRC Table R602.7(2) (one floor only) to get a header good for 10psf dead load plus 40psf live load. To get the 7ft, the bed header's tributary width is 3.5ft. For a 7ft wide house, the interior load bearing wall's tributary width is 3.5ft with 1.75ft carried by each exterior wall. Note that if 2 pieces of lumber carry 50psf, then 1 of those pieces will carry 25psf.

Comment: Is this bed located in a corner with two walls coming together? Will it be located against at least one exterior wall? What size is the mattress?